# Regex to allow numbers only between 1 and 20000

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javascript and I am using a regex expression for validating whether the values is between 1 and 20000
         `^(?:[1-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:[1-9][0-9][0-9])|(?:[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|(?:[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|(?:20000))$`

This is the expression I tried but it allows 99999 as valid

Comment: Why don't you convert to numbers, and compare them?

Comment: `text<=20000 and text>=1` should also work.

Comment: I need it with regex

Comment: Please give us even a one single rational reason for why this should be done with RegExp. You probably won't use a spoon to dig a ditch, though it's possible ...

Comment: I want to validate the values dynamically if call a function using any events it will cause me a performance issue, since my application is large

Comment: FYI: Complicated regex can cause performance issues too.

Comment: Well your requirements fit more of a number comparison rather than pattern matching. Regex should be used for pattern matching rather than number comparison. I dont say its not possible but its unnecessary to make a complex pattern to match that range. I suggest you can use number field to reduce your complexity and keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: This is naive to try to solve with Regex when you obviously don't have to. You didn't even take into consideration if the value for example is `0000019293` or `00019383,29192`, or `18293.23292`. Does Regex know which notation of the decimal separator is a comma or dot? So many issues you can easily avoid by just using JavaScript for what it's made for.

Comment: `<input type="number" min="2" max="19999">`

Comment: @Teemu We can never rely on client-side validation. It's only a simple front-line defence mechanism.

Comment: @Allendar Ofcourse not, but the subject of the question is client-side validation.

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm doubtful this is the most-efficient solution, this should do the trick.

```
/^((1[0-9]{0,4})|([1-9][0-9]{0,3})|20000)$/
```

Be warned that this is string-matching, not type-casting, so things like decimal places and zero-filling will not be matched.

### [Regex Explained](http://tinyurl.com/jgz9lyy):

[image: graph]

### Unit test I used:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
 var should = i > 0 && i <= 20000;
 if (should !== /^((1[0-9]{0,4})|([1-9][0-9]{0,3})|20000)$/.test('' + i)) {
  console.log('FAILED:', i);
 }
}
console.log('DONE');
```

Comment: Decimals, thousand separators, zero fill, not knowing the separator localised standard, etc. will still fail here.

Comment: It's true, they will.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Your answer is very good. Downvoters are rather "slow" these days, they forget that answers here are not for just every occasion, but might be specifically tailored for each OP problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
^1?\d{0,4}$
```

I think you should use number comparison for better performance.
I hope that helps.